# Different results for SHA-1 hashing between Groovy and Python

Tags: groovy, sha1

This question is related to my query titled "Create WS security headers for REST web service in SoapUI Pro". However that one is different as I raised that because I couldn't get the script to work at all, I came up with a solution for that but it only works about 66% of the time.

I have noticed that the code that I use to hash the string *sometimes* produces different results when compared to a python script hashing the same input.

Below is my groovy code that hashes an input value.

```
MessageDigest cript2 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        cript2.update(nonce.getBytes("ASCII"));
        PasswordDigest = new String(cript2.digest());
```

If I run it with the input nonce value 201703281329 it produces the below 
ë±ËËÐùìÓ0¼ÕM�¹,óßP‹

If I use the same input value using the Python code below then it produces ëﾱËËÐùìÓ0ﾼÕMﾏﾹ,óßPﾋ

```
digest = sha.new(nonce).digest()
```

However if I run the groovy and python scripts with input value 201703281350 then they both produce ..

iàvè©®É¹m:F Ë Â¾

Could someone tell me why I am seeing differences for some input values and not others and how I can modify my groovy code so that it produces same values as Python code?

much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compare the bytes returned by the digest method of both languages, you'll find that they are indeed the same. The reason is that some combinations of bytes do not result in printable Java Strings.

To compare them:

```
def hexString = PasswordDigest.collect { String.format('%02x', it) }.join()
```

Compare to the output of `sha.hexdigest()`:

```
def hexString = sha.new(nonce).hexdigest()
```

Both should produce `ebb1cbcbd0f9ecd330bcd51b4d8fb92cf3df508b`

**Edited**

Perhaps I didn't make it clear that passwordDigest **should not be converted to a String**. Below is the complete groovy and python code. Both programs produce the same output:

Groovy:

```
import java.security.*

String nonce = '201703281329'
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
digest.update(nonce.getBytes("ASCII"))

byte[] passwordDigest = digest.digest() // byte[], not string

String hexString = passwordDigest.collect { String.format('%02x', it) }.join()

println hexString
```

Python:

```
import sha

nonce = '201703281329'
sha.new(nonce).hexdigest()
print sha.new(nonce).hexdigest()
```

The output of both: `ebb1cbcbd0f9ecd330bcd51b4d8fb92cf3df508b`.

Comment: Hi sjtai. Thanks for your answer, however I've found that they don't produce the same result. The groovy code def hexString = PasswordDigest.getBytes().collect{String.format('%02x', it)}.join() produces ebb1cbcbd0f9ecd330bcd51b4d3fb92cf3df508b whereas the python code hexString = sha.new(CREATIONDATE).hexdigest() produces ebb1cbcbd0f9ecd330bcd51b4d8fb92cf3df508b. Which is 1 char different 3 vs 8.

Comment: Thanks Sjtai. Sorry for late reply. Didn't see your edits. This is where I was going wrong. I actually posted my full problem on this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483218/create-ws-security-headers-for-rest-web-service-in-soapui-pro?noredirect=1#comment72106195_42483218 and have updated the answer after making changes from your suggestion the script creates the correct password digest value all the time now and not just some of the time as it was before.